# Reverse proxy with ssh

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, putty, ssh-tunnel, reverse-tunnel

I have the following setup:

> A: my linux laptop at home
>  B: a Windows machine to which I have
>   access via VNC, this PC is behind a restrictive firewall 
>  C: a PLC
>   on the same subnet as B

I'd like to create a tunnel between A:port1 and C:port2 via B, so that initiaing a connection from A to localhost:port1 would end up connecting to C:port2.

Can this be done by connecting from B to A via ssh and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to use ssh, you can

A) connect from A to B via ssh with port forwarding, if you have a ssh server on B, e.g.

```
user@A $  ssh -L 1122:C:1122 B
```

B) connect from B to A via ssh, with reverse port forwarding, if you are ok with ssh access from B to A

```
user@B $  ssh -R 1122:C:1122 A
```

If you choose approach B, you can reduce, but not eliminate exposure to your A computer, as ssh access can be limited to port fowarding. For example by authenticating via pubkey, with restrictions set in authorized_keys.

```
auser@A $ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
restrict,port-forwarding ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIGiHycmak/rgoAF+A+wG+K8Rk2iYhcVXcuFiajEOxHe3 buser

buser@B $ ssh -v -R 1122:C:1122 -N -i path/to/my/key auser@A
```